# How can I word wrap text if the image is on the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get some text to wrap around an image placed on the right (for an image placed on left, it is wrapping automatically). Any ideas on how to do this? Here's what I have now.

```
<div class="row clear">
    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
          <div class="heading">Blash blah blsh</div>
                <div class="feature-txt-body">This is a long piece of text that is so long that it needs to break into multiple lines. I am now writing some jibberish text and I have no idea what I am writing. I need to <b>only</b> focus on what's relevant to you. Now if you look at this line, it is not wrapping around the image.</div>
          </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div id="image"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap's `.pull-right` class  (which is basically just a float:right) to achieve this without using columns.

You can see it working in this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/sc6dvO9rj3

HTML (tidied up a bit):

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="pull-right" width="100" height="100" src="..." />
  <h1>Blah blah blah</h1>
  <p>
      This is a long piece of text that is so long that it needs to break into multiple lines. I am now writing some jibberish text and I have no idea what I am writing. I need to <strong>only</strong> focus on what's relevant to you. Now if you look at this line, it is not wrapping around the image.
  </p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/86ab6g47/1/)

```
<div class="row clear">
    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
          <div class="heading">Blash blah blsh</div>
                <div class="feature-txt-body"> 
     <div class="col-md-3">
     <div id="image" style="background:#000; width:200px; height:100px; float:right;"></div>
     </div>This is a long piece of text that is so long that it needs to break into multiple lines. I am now writing some jibberish text and I have no idea what I am writing. I need to <b>only</b> focus on what's relevant to you. Now if you look at this line, it is not wrapping around the image.This is a long piece of text that is so long that it needs to break into multiple lines. I am now writing some jibberish text and I have no idea what I am writing. I need to <b>only</b> focus on what's relevant to you. Now if you look at this line, it is not wrapping around the image. This is a long piece of text that is so long that it needs to break into multiple lines. I am now writing some jibberish text and I have no idea what I am writing. I need to <b>only</b> focus on what's relevant to you. Now if you look at this line, it is not wrapping around the image</div>
          </div>

</div>
```

put image within text div will make it float to the right of the text in wrapping manner

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is not working. It is further pushing the image to the right when I do this.

Comment: yes i saw that in fiddle im trying to do that if i get another way i will post here

Comment: i got the answer but not a conventional method

Answer (score 0):

Works with plain, boring html:

```
<img align="right" src="..." />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpvk2sLt/

I would recommend the CSS variant `float:right` as well though